# Web3.js function(s) to help determine the block numbers inside a date range?

Tags: web3js, javascript, events, blocks

I just learned today that you can query past events using the Web3.js 1.0.0 **getPastEvents()** function.  That function supports filtering via the *fromBlock* and *toBlock* call parameters, so you can limit your query to a specific range of blocks:

```
getPastEvents("something", { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: "latest" }
```

Are there functions in Web3.js that can help you determine the *from* and *to* block numbers needed to cover a desired date range when calling *getPastEvents()*?  Or is there another method/technique that works directly with dates instead of block numbers when querying for events that you can use instead of *getPastEvents()*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method for this in web3js 0.2x.x/1.0.0.

You can implement this by yourself, but you'll have to build-up the index for timestamps first. Alternatively, you could apply halving the interval method like when guessing numbers.